# how to build a project using msbuild without its dependencies

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, msbuild

I would to build a c++ project created by vs2013 in command line, just like when you right click on the project in vs, select project only
[image]

But instead of doing so in vs, I would like to build it using command line(msbuild).

How can I achieve that?

I tried

```
msbuild mysolution.sln /t:myproject, while set msbuildemitsolution=1
```

But it is not working, it still builds its dependency.

Comment: You can try option /p:BuildProjectReferences=false. I'm not sure whether it works or not.

Comment: msbuild myproject.vcxproj ?